# DatePickerDialog display bug on Samsung galaxy S7 run Android 7.x

Tags: android

[image]

Only Samsung s7 run android 7.x

Here my code

```
 DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(activity
                ,new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year
                                          , int monthOfYear
                                          , int dayOfMonth) {
                        listener.onDateSet(year, monthOfYear, dayOfMonth);
                    }
                }
                ,c.get(Calendar.YEAR)
                , c.get(Calendar.MONTH)
                , c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));

        int firstDayOfWeek = TimeUtils.getFirstDayOfWeek(activity);
        datePickerDialog.getDatePicker().setFirstDayOfWeek(firstDayOfWeek);
        datePickerDialog.show();
```

Someone advise me how to solve this problem?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You don't set custom style for dialog so this normal(default style). If you want "fix" this "bug" you must create custom style dialog.

Comment: yes. i have set theme for it. but not work. You have tutorial custom style. here my code `<style name="MyPickerDialog" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/primary</item>
    </style>`

Comment: you don't understand you must edit margin and padding in custom style not only change color :D

Comment: Yes. but how much value? because I set margin and padding is 0dp it not work.

Comment: probably you must start in root(android:Widget.DatePicker) and edit many stuff and go up or create own layout to calendar and replace default

this default layout for dataPicker 

https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/date_picker_legacy.xml

Comment: I think problem from google support v7 if I use version 25.1.0 or newer.

Comment: I create new Layout with DatePicker and I see same problem :)

Comment: only copy all and set 
android:id="@+id/pickers" android:layout_width="match_parent"

Comment: Yep. match_parent

Comment: my last thought
set in your customs style
contentInset End="0dp"
contentInset Right="0dp"
this work in toolbar...

I have no more ideas..... sorry

Answer (score 0):

For me works fine on the same device, I extend DialogFrament in my app and use code like this:

```
public static class DatePickerFragment extends DialogFragment
                            implements DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener {

    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Use the current date as the default date in the picker
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        int year = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        int month = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        int day = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Create a new instance of DatePickerDialog and return it
        return new DatePickerDialog(getActivity(), this, year, month, day);
    }

    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int day) {
        // Do something with the date chosen by the user
    }
}
```

and then use this method on the view I need to open the dialog:

```
public void showDatePickerDialog(View v) {
    DialogFragment newFragment = new DatePickerFragment();
    newFragment.show(getSupportFragmentManager(), "datePicker");
}
```

Try to implement this or follow the guide on the developer site:
https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/controls/pickers.html

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the actual implementation of `DatePickerDialog`'s UI is device specific and it can have some issues.

I've got similar issues on devices with the screen width smaller than 360dp. Fixed this by using `THEME_HOLO_LIGHT` theme.

`DatePickerDialog` has a constructor which accepts a theme:

```
DatePickerDialog(Context context, int theme, DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener callBack, int year, int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth)
```

You may use one of the following:

- AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_DARK
- AlertDialog.THEME_DEVICE_DEFAULT_LIGHT
- AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_DARK
- AlertDialog.THEME_HOLO_LIGHT
- AlertDialog.THEME_TRADITIONAL